# When Android app gets updated how to get back data about the user from the shared preferences?

Tags: android, installation, google-play, apk

I have an `Android` app and I want to know, when a user updates my app from Play Store, what `Android` does in background? Does it uninstall the current version of my app and then install a new version?

I am facing a problem here that, suppose a user is logged in in my app and then he updates the app. Now all of my details about the user which was saved in my `SharedPreferences` will get lost and when the new version will get installed then this user have to log in again because as there will be no data in my `SharedPreferences`. I don't want my user to log in again, I want to save the state somewhere so that when the app gets updated user does not have to log in again.

Can anyone one of you tell me how all `Android` apps implement this functionality?

Comment: It should not uninstall/reinstall on an update from the Play Store.  It should just do an upgrade install and leave all SharedPreferences intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... when a user updates my app from Play Store, what `Android` does in background? Does it uninstall the current version of my app and then install a new version?

No. Once a new version of `apk` file has been downloaded from Play Store on a device, `Android` (or more precisely [`PackageManager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#PackageManager)) reinstalls it keeping app's data untouched by using, AFAIK, at least [`-r`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#pm) option (*or a call to the corresponding method of `PackageManager`*).

That said, your `SharedPreferences` with the user login data will be kept after update.